# File not found error in xcode compile

Tags: ios, xcode, nsunknownkeyexception

In my xcode project, I recompiled my project for testing rather than running and I received the following error message.

```
    (null): File not found:    /Users/joeblow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cemweb-bwtaoodqbazinlcmawaglbwwiqgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Cemweb.app/Cemweb
```

However, if I compile for running I do not get the above error. The reason I recompiled the project for testing is because I was continually getting **an NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:'**  error for every control in my app.
Is the above error related to this error and how can I resolve the file not found error?

Comment: NSUnknownKeyException was raised on which method call?

Comment: The program that showed the error was in my delegate.m as shown as follows:                                                                                                           #import "CEMAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CEMAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: Please, add an All Exceptions breakpoint and run the code again. See this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvnqBjzEKuk

Comment: I added the All Exceptions breakpoint and I get the following message:  'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x12fd033c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ellamartinLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182d1a59c 0x1934180e4 0x182d1a220 0x183b25ab0 0x182c473c0 0x1878d4020 0x1878d5e28 0x187754a9c 0x187753ce0 0x1877524a0 0x18af8962c 0x182cd2a28 0x182cd1b30 0x182ccfd30 0x182bfd0a4 0x187533aac 0x18752eaa4 0x10010297c 0x193a86a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: What am I looking for after running it again?  I can see the assembler code but have no way of knowing what to look for.

Comment: Important new information "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ellamartinLabel". Add a property with this name a run the app again.